# <img src="Username:Password@Url /> safer way?

Tags: php, html, ftp, image

I am currently using the following method to recieve images from my FTP server: `<img src="Username:Password@Url />`, however, I was wondering wether there exists any safer way to do this?

**PHP is available.**

Comment: Well, are those images *public*, or are they supposed to be password protected?

Comment: even if security isn't an issue, you gonna screw your ftp server

Comment: I feel like this is not a great way of doing this.   Putting your ftp password in the src is a big security risk.   You should find a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't condone requesting images like this, but you could request the contents of the image via something `file_get_contents` (or even better [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) and save it to your server. Like so (am using file_get_contents for speed of example, definitely use cURL):

```
$image = file_get_contents('Username:Password@Url');
file_put_contents('image.jpg', $image);
```

Then..

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 3):

You really should consider not having them on your FTP server. There would be no way to protect the password. You should have a PHP page that streams them from FTP over HTTP.